# How to Hide Toolbars from QGIS1.7 programmatically?

Tags: qgis

I am a beginner to QGIS 1.7 and getting problem in hiding the toolbar.
I am using:

```
fileTB = self.iface.fileToolBar() 
fileTB.setVisible(False)
```

This does not work but doesn't give an error either.

I also tried:

```
self.iface.mainWindow().removeToolBar(fileTB)
```

This permanently removes the toolbar

```
fileTB.clear()
```

but I don't want that, because I want it to be get invisible, when the user click the 'on' button it should get displayed.

Update:

```
def initGui(self): # I used this one 
    fileTB = self.iface.fileToolBar() 
    fileTB.setVisible(False) # As You suggested me qgis.utils.iface.fileToolBar().setVisible(False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work OK my end.

Try running this in the python console to see if it will hide the toolbar.

```
qgis.utils.iface.fileToolBar().setVisible(False)
```

Comment: Yes If i am trying it using python console ,it is working but programmetically it is not.....

Comment: can you post a sample of your plugin?